# How do I toggle visibility settings between images in React and Ant Design?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am creating a page to display badges as I implement gamification features to my project. Right now, I want to display a 'grey' badge when the user has not unlocked the badge. Something like this:

[image]

Once the user has unlocked the badge, a 'bronze' badge will be displayed instead.

[image]

I am using Ant Design to make the card component to display the badge. The code currently looks like this. I don't know how to toggle the visibility between the badges. They are supposed to occupy the same space. Unless there is a better way to do it.

```
<Col span={6}>
    <Card type ='flex' align = 'middle'>
        Atta Boy!
        <img src="/greysmall.png" justify = 'center'/>
        Card content
    </Card>
 </Col>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a ternary operation that shows one or the other based on a bool value?

```
<Col span={6}>
    <Card type ='flex' align = 'middle'>
        Atta Boy!
        {isBadgeEarned
           ? <img src="/success.png" justify = 'center'/>
           : <img src="/greysmall.png" justify = 'center'/>
         }
        Card content
    </Card>
 </Col>
```

Comment: Ah that could work! I'm new to react and javascript so thank you!